# Access default dialer running in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am launching my activity when the user launches the dialer app on his device . There is an edit box in my activity .
My requirement is whenever i type any number on my edit box in my activity , it should automatically reflect in the dialer app running behind my activity , so that when i exit my activity ,i could see the number in the diaer which i entered in the editbox of my activity .

any hint how to proceed . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in "real time"

The only way to achieve this is to send an Intent to the dialer when the user finished typind the number:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1231231234"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to call the number immediatly , You can use action `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.
Also add required permission in manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but there must be some way like when i entered any number in my editbox, my dialer app which is in background attains priority of foreground process and my app becomes background process ?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Do not forget that there are many dialer apps and you wont be able to do this for all.. You should use standart tools I pointed.